# XSLT 2.0 accessing attributes in hash map

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to access a value of an attribute, but when I try to it doesn't output nothing.
This is my xslt definition of the map.

`<xsl:variable name="fieldsDataSources">
                <entry key="PrintDate">new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")</entry>
                <entry key="PrintTime">new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")</entry>
                <entry key="PageNumber">$V{PAGE_NUMBER}</entry>
</xsl:variable>`

And then this is how I call it.

`<coso3><xsl:value-of select="$fieldsDataSources/entry[@key=@DataSource]"/></coso3>
 <coso><xsl:value-of select="$fieldsDataSources/entry[@key='PrintDate']"/></coso>
 <coso2><xsl:value-of select="@DataSource"/></coso2>`

This is the output:

`<coso3/>
 <coso>new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")</coso>
 <coso2>PrintDate</coso2>`

As you can see, I can't access the value of the enrty PrintDate using an attribute that contains the string PrintDate, I hope you can help me know how to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want `<coso3><xsl:value-of select="$fieldsDataSources/entry[@key = current()/@DataSource]"/></coso3>`, assuming you want to compare the `key` attribute of the `entry` element to the `DataSource` of the outer context node (e.g. of a template or for-each).

In general I would suggest to define a key `<xsl:key name="format" match="entry" use="@key"/>` and then use `<coso3><xsl:value-of select="key('format', @DataSource, $fieldsDataSources)"/></coso3>`.